# How can I make this sql query faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a table user_notifications that has 1100000 records and I have to run this below query but it takes more than 3 minutes to complete the query what can I do to improve the fetch time.

```
SELECT `user_notifications`.`user_id`
FROM `user_notifications`
WHERE `user_notifications`.`notification_template_id` = 175
AND (DATE(sent_at) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 day))
AND `user_notifications`.`user_id` IN (
  1203, 1282, 1499, 2244, 2575, 2697, 2828, 2900, 3085, 3989,
  5264, 5314, 5368, 5452, 5603, 6133, 6498..
)
```

the user ids in `IN` block are sometimes upto 1k.

for optimisation I have indexed on `user_id` and `notification_template_id` column in `user_notification` table.

[image]

Comment: Comparing 1000 `user_id` values for 1+ million records is going to take some time, even if MySQL is using the index as you want.  How long is "ages?"

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen 2-5 minutes avg

Comment: Did you create separate indexes on user_id and notification_template_id or one for both? Try the latter.

Comment: @wumpz seperate index. please see my attached screenshot. How can I create one for both?

Comment: `create index my_compound_index on user_notifications(user_id, notification_template_id)`

Comment: What are the datatypes of `notification_template_id` and `user_id`?

Comment: @FuzzyTree - Swap the order; put the `=` first.

Comment: @RickJames I generally would agree but the cardinality of `notification_template_id` is far lower than that of `user_id` (534 vs 66720), so it's hard to tell which order would be faster in this case

Comment: @FuzzyTree - Cardinality is not relevant here.  `IN` versus `=` _is_ relevant.

Comment: @RickJames I think both are relevant. Higher cardinality means more rows can be eliminated in an index scan whereas a higher number of elements in an `IN` list means less rows can be eliminated in an index scan. For an extreme example suppose the `IN` list has only 1 element and the cardinality of `notification_template_id` was 1 (i.e. always the same).

Comment: An index works best if it does not need to read, then ignore, any records.  Even better if all the records are contiguous.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Big IN() lists are inherently slow.  Create a temporary table with an index and put the values in the IN() list into that tempory table instead, then you'll get the power of an indexed join instead of giant IN() list.

Comment: Thanks @Dan it seems logical. can you please tell me is there something we can do for sent_at field also, I think this is also causing the delay in query.

Comment: @Prem do you have any facts to support that opinion?  codeforester addresses it, and my comment to that answer is relevant also.  But your IN clause is almost certainly what's causing the majority of the delay.

Comment: I have seen problems with 70K items in `IN()`, but not with 1K.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be querying for a small date range.  How about having an index based on SENT_AT column?  Do you know what index the current query is using?

Comment: also on that theme, do you really have to convert `sent_at` to a DATE?  Seems like getting rid of that cast would yield the same results, since if DATE(sent_at) is bigger than a given value, then sent_at itself would have to be at least that big.

Comment: @DanFarrell Not 100% sure, but I'll bet the 1000 user ID comparisons is what is killing this query.

Comment: DATE(sent_at) could be problematic because it might prevent the use of any sent_at based index because of the function call, unless you have a function based index.

Comment: `INDEX(sent_at)` is definitely not as good (for this query) as `INDEX(notification_template_id, sent_at)`.  Equals first, then one range.

Answer (score 1):

(1)  Don't hide columns in functions if you might need to use an index:

```
AND (DATE(sent_at) >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 4 day))
```

-->

```
AND sent_at >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 day
```

(2) Use a "composite" index for

```
WHERE `notification_template_id` = 175
  AND sent_at >= ...
  AND `user_id` IN (...)
```

The first column should be the one with '='.  It is unclear what to put next, so I suggest adding both of these indexes:

```
INDEX(notification_template_id, user_id, sent_at)
INDEX(notification_template_id, sent_at)
```

The Optimizer will probably pick between them correctly.

Composite indexes are *not* the same as indexes on the individual columns.

(3) Yes, you *could* try putting the IN list in a tmp table, but the cost of doing such might outweigh the benefit.  I don't think of 1K values in `IN()` as being "too many".

(4) [*My cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) on building indexes.

Comment: If  I need to create composite_index INDEX(notification_template_id, user_id, sent_at) do I need to delete seperate indexes?

Comment: Think about it this way...  When a list of names is sorted by lastname, it is 'impossible' to search for someone by _just_ firstname.  So, no, do not delete any other indexes (without first discovering that nothing else might need them).

Comment: My indexes may or may not be useful for _other_ queries.